# Can JTextArea's text look like console?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea

I was building a tic tac toe game for the terminal and it prints out nicely there using System.out.print and System.out.println.
 Now, I'm moving it up to a GUI and my first instinct was to use a JTextArea since it can be multiline and after every turn just reset the text in the TextArea. However, apparently here (in the JTextArea), every character seems to take up a different amount of space and the board doesn't line up well at all. *Is there a way to make the text in the JTextArea print like the console where every character occupies the same space?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you want to use

```
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 40);
    Font font = new Font("Segoe Script", Font.BOLD, 20);
    textArea.setFont(font);
```

and select a [monospace font](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13148/which-fonts-have-the-same-width-for-every-character) (every char occupies the same space)

Comment: Solved it perfectly. Thanks! The issue was the font. Learned a new fact about Monospace :) Appreciate it

Comment: It’s better to use [Font.MONOSPACED](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Font.html#MONOSPACED), which will work on every platform, for the first argument.  Non-Windows computers are unlikely to have Segoe fonts.